# click the content slide up and slide down the following content?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 <table>
    <tr class="clicke">
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/title_.gif" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="690" height="65"
            border="0" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_even">
        <td class="required">Name (First, Middle Initial, Last)</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="realname" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_odd">
        <td>Birth Date</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Birth Date" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="clicke">
        <td colspan="2">
            <img src="images/informati.gif" vspace="0" hspace="0" width="690" height="65"
            border="0" alt="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_odd">
        <td>Present Address</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="Present Address" style="width:250px;" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_even">
        <td class="required">City</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="City" value="credit-application.php" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

when click the `clicke class tr`, the following tr  will hide with slow up untill the next  `clicke` tr. when click again, the following tr content will show with slow down.

my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clicke").click(function(){
        $("tr").slideToggle("slow");
    }

    );
  });
```

but all the tr are effect, which are not i want, how to  determine the related tr content. thank you

i am sorry maybe i didn't say the question clear.
eg:

```
<tr class="clicke">

        </tr>


click the tr. those tr will be show/hide



<tr class="tbl_even">
            <td class="required">Name (First, Middle Initial, Last)</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="realname" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tbl_odd">
            <td>Birth Date</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Birth Date" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: The tr format doesn't seems quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I see you've updated your question to make your intent clearer. I think the best way to achieve what you want is to group the form fields in one element, and toggle that element.

I think this is preferable to animating multiple table rows simultaneously, since I assume your goal is to animate all the associated fields at once, in a single animation.

Here's how you might do that:

```
<h2 class="clicke">CLICK ME #1</h2>
<table>
    <tr class="tbl_even">
      <td class="required">Name (First, Middle Initial, Last)</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="realname" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_odd">
      <td>Birth Date</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Birth Date" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<h2 class="clicke">CLICK ME #2</h2>
<table>
    <tr class="tbl_odd">
      <td>Present Address</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="Present Address" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tbl_even">
      <td class="required">City</td>
      <td><input type="text" name="City" /></td>
    </tr>
</table>​​​
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.clicke').next('table').hide();
    $('.clicke').click(function(){
        $(this).next('table').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvFQm/1/

Comment: i am sorry. maybe i told the question more ambiguous. i don't want to show/hide the self tr. but the following tr.

Comment: Apply display: block to the tables. I've updated my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZvFQm/

Comment: i want to the default state of the table content are hidden. when i addded this line  $(this).next("table").hide(); but it doesn't work. why? thank you

Comment: You probably put your hide() call inside of the click event handler. I've amended my answer to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try This, It will work.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".clicke").click(function(){
        $(this).nextAll("tr:eq(0), tr:eq(1)").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Doesn't work because the event handler IS the tr - there are no more table rows to find inside it.

Comment: i am sorry maybe i didn't say the question clear. i have updated the question, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not secure to have correctly understend, but this could be a solution:

```
$(".clicke").toggle(
    function(){
        $(this).parent().find("tr").eq(1).hide();

},function(){
         $(this).parent().find("tr").eq(1).show();

} );
```

See [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/TPxHy/) to see the result

Answer (score 0):

Please try editing the table format like in demo
[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/hQKFf/)

All it does is find next `.slide` table and perform `slideToggle`

```
    $(".clicke").click(function(){
        $(this).next('tr').find('.slide').slideToggle("slow");
    });
```